# What is the definition of "sender" in gmails Email sender guidelines?

Tags: gmail

Googles [email sender guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en&sjid=6434587003879206191-EU) states that "senders who send more than 5,000 messages per day to Gmail accounts must meet the requirements in this section.".  **What does it mean by "sender" in that context?  Is it a mailbox, all mailboxes on a domain or a mail server? (or something else)**

Background: I do not send over 5000 emails a day from my mailbox nor from all mailboxes across my domain.  But I do use a shared email provider.  I am sure that across all their users, the shared email provider will send more that 5,000 emails from their mail server to gmail on a daily basis.  Does the definition of a "sender" cover from an originating mailbox, an originating domain or the total for all mail from a mail server?

It is clear that sending 5000 emails a day is the trigger point, but I cannot find any documentation about whether a "sender" is a mailbox, all mailboxes on a domain or a mail server.